# What's causing the pointer to reset?

Tags: c++, inheritance, linked-list

I'm working on a program for class that creates a Linked List off of a templated class to hold information about Students, Faculty, and Administration. Student, Administrator, and Faculty all inherit a class called Person. My problem is in my list class along with my RecordsOffice class, when the program leaves the addToList function, the head pointer resets it's data and I can't see what I have just added to the list.

This is the TemplatedList class

```
//Author:Angelo Todaro
//TemplatedList.h
//Header file for the TemplatedList class

#include "person.h"
#include "student.h"
#include "administrator.h"
#include "faculty.h"

using namespace std;
#ifndef TemplatedList_H
#define TemplatedList_H

template<class T> 
struct Node{
    T *data;
    Node *next;
};


template <class T, typename T2>
class TemplatedList{
public:
    /*Default Constructor
    *Constructs an object of the TemplatedList class*/
    TemplatedList();

    /*Default Destructor
    *Destructs an object of the TemplatedList class*/
    ~TemplatedList();

    /*Accessor Method for head node
    *Provides user access to the value of the head node*/
    T getHead() const;

    /*Modifier Method for head node
    *Provides the user access to change the value of the head node*/
    void setHead(T *newHead);

    /*addToList
    *Adds a Student to the list*/
    void addToList(T *newStudent);

    /*deleteFromList
    *Deletes a Student from the list*/
    void deleteFromList(T2 number);

    /*printStudent
    *prints the information of the specified student*/
    void printSingle(T2 number);

    /*printList
    *prints the entire list of students*/
    void printList();

private:
    T *head;
};

#endif


/*Default Constructor
*Constructs an object of the TemplatedList class*/
template <class T, typename T2>
TemplatedList<T,T2>::TemplatedList(){
    head = new T;
    head->next=NULL;
    head->data=NULL;
}

/*Default Destructor
*Destructs an object of the TemplatedList class*/
template <class T, typename T2>
TemplatedList<T,T2>::~TemplatedList(){
    delete head;
    head=NULL;
}

/*Accessor Method for head node
*Provides user access to the value of the head node*/
template <class T, typename T2>
T TemplatedList<T,T2>::getHead() const{
    return head;
}

/*Modifier Method for head node
*Provides the user access to change the value of the head node*/
template <class T, typename T2>
void TemplatedList<T,T2>::setHead(T *newHead){
    head=newHead;
}

/*addToList
*Adds a Person to the list*/
template <class T, typename T2>
void TemplatedList<T,T2>::addToList(T *newPerson){
    T *curr=head;
    T *prev=curr;
    cout << "Adding ";
    newPerson->data->print();
    cout << endl;
    if(head->next==NULL && head->data==NULL)//if list has not been initialized
    {

        head->data=newPerson->data;
        head->data->print();
        head->next=NULL;
    }
    //if new Person's M Number is less than the head's MNumber
    else if(newPerson->data->getMNumber()<head->data->getMNumber())
    {
        newPerson->next=head->next;
        head = newPerson;
    }
    else //all other cases
    {
        while(curr!=NULL && 
                newPerson->data->getMNumber()>curr->data->getMNumber())
        {
            prev=curr;
            curr=curr->next;
        }
            newPerson->next=curr;
            prev->next= newPerson;
        if(curr==NULL)
            newPerson->next=NULL;
    }

}

/*deleteFromList
*Deletes a Person from the list*/
template <class T, typename T2>
void TemplatedList<T,T2>::deleteFromList(T2 number){
    T *curr=head;
    T *prev=head;
    if(head==NULL||head->next==NULL){
        cout << "Can not delete Person (M" << number << "), NOT found!" << endl;
    }
    //if first Person is equal to the selected one to delete
    else if(curr->data->getMNumber()==number)
    {
        prev->next=curr->next;
        delete curr;
        curr=NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        while(curr!=NULL &&
            curr->data->getMNumber()!=number)
        {
            prev=curr;
            curr=curr->next;
        }
        if(curr!=NULL)//If not at end of list
        {
            prev->next=curr->next;
            delete curr;
            curr = NULL;

        }
        else//there is no listing
        {
            cout << "Can not delete Person (M" << number << "), NOT found!" << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}

/*printPerson
*prints the information of the specified Person*/
template <class T, typename T2>
void TemplatedList<T,T2>::printSingle(T2 number){
    T *curr=head;
    T *prev=curr;
    while(curr!=NULL && curr->data->getMNumber()!=number)
    {
        prev=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    if(curr!=NULL)//if match is found
    {
        curr->data->print();
    }
    else//there is no listing
    {
        cout << "Can not print person (M" << number << "), NOT found!" << endl << endl;
    }

}

/*printList
*prints the entire list of Persons*/
template <class T, typename T2>
void TemplatedList<T,T2>::printList(){
    T *curr=head;
    T *prev=curr;
    while(curr!=NULL)
    {
        curr->data->print();
        prev=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Here is the implementation of the RecordsOffice class

```
//Author:Angelo Todaro
//recordsOffice.cpp
//Implementation file for the RecordsOffice class

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>
#include "recordsOffice.h"


/*Default Constructor
Creates an object of the RecordsOffice class*/
RecordsOffice::RecordsOffice(){

}

/*Default Destructor
*Destructs an object of the RecordsOffice class*/
RecordsOffice::~RecordsOffice(){


}

/*Accessor Method for List of Persons
*Provides the user with a way to retrieve m_List*/
TemplatedList<Node<Person>,int> RecordsOffice::getList() const{
    return m_List;
}

/*Modifier Method for List of Persons
*provides a way for the user to modify m_List*/
void RecordsOffice::setList(TemplatedList<Node<Person>,int> newList){
    m_List = newList;
}



/*parseCommands
*parses the command entered and calls appropriate function*/
void RecordsOffice::parseCommands(string fileName){
    ifstream infile;//create new file stream
    infile.open(fileName);//opens file
    assert(infile);//check for valid file
    char command;//stores the value of the current command

    while(infile >> command)
    {
        if(command=='A')
        {
            string name, email, title;//temporary strings  to hold values of Person
            int mnumber;//temporary ints to hold values of Person
            infile >> name >> mnumber >> email >> title;
            Administrator admin = Administrator(name,mnumber,email,title);
            Node<Person> *newper = new Node<Person>;
            newper->data=&admin;
            newper->next=NULL;
            m_List.addToList(newper);
        }
        else if(command=='F')
        {

            string name, email, department;//temporary strings  to hold values of Person
            int mnumber;//temporary ints to hold values of Person
            bool tenured;
            infile >> name >> mnumber >> email >> department >> tenured;
            Faculty fac= Faculty(name,mnumber,email,tenured,department);
            Node<Person> *newper = new Node<Person>;
            newper->data=&fac;
            newper->next=NULL;
            m_List.addToList(newper);
        }
        else if(command=='S')
        {
            string name, email, major;//temporary strings  to hold values of Person
            int mnumber, year;//temporary ints to hold values of Person
            infile >> name >> mnumber >> email >> year >> major;
            Student stu= Student(name,mnumber,email,year,major);
            Node<Person> *newper = new Node<Person>;
            newper->data=&stu;
            newper->next=NULL;
            m_List.addToList(newper);
        }
        else if(command=='D')
        {
                int mnum;//int to store mnumber
                infile >> mnum;
                cout << "Deleting M" << mnum << endl;
                m_List.deleteFromList(mnum);
        }
        else if(command=='P')
        {
                int mnum;//int to store mnumber
                infile >> mnum;
                cout << "Printing M" << mnum << endl;
                m_List.printSingle(mnum);
        }
        else if(command=='L')
        {
                cout << "Listing all Persons" << endl;
                m_List.printList();
        }

    }
}
```

The file that the program is reading in contains

```
A   Doe 4444    jdoe3@mtsu.com  President
L
P   4444
F   Johnson 2222    cjLittle@mtsu.com   English 0
P   2222
S   Reed    9999    reed@mtsu.com   1   History
P   9999
L
D   9999
D   2222
D   4444
```

Comment: Can you use a debugger with memory breakpoints ?

Comment: Basically what I have gotten is that is adds it into the list successfully, because it prints the information out from the head variable after I said head->data=newPerson->data;. I'm fairly certain the problem is when I leave the addToList function due to the fact that when I move into the printList function the head->data is all reset.

Comment: Administrator, Faculty, Student are declared on Stack, and you are getting address to these. When you do m_List.addToList(newper); and newper contains newper->data = &something-on-stack, the newper->data becomes invalid as soon as you return from the call. You need to new Administrator, Faculty, etc to keep it in the memory. It still may not not be the reason for your problem, but you *will* see this at some point 100%.

Comment: What does the *entire* program have to do with *one* pointer being reset?

Comment: @synxis I have and it resets the changes the memory at the address pointed to by head->data when I move into the next function.

Comment: @Grzegorz I'm confused as to where you would new Administrator, etc.

Comment: @David It will do it for every member added to the list.

Comment: @todaroa: Instead of 'Administrator admin = Administrator(name,mnumber,email,title);' use 'Administrator* admin = new Administrator(name,mnumber,email,title);' Of course you need to change your program to accomodate this change. You need to change Student, and Faculty too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`newper->data` always points to local variables, when local variables go out of scope, they are actually released, `newper->data` no longer points to valid data. You need to use dynamic storage duration by `new`.

```
Administrator admin = Administrator(name,mnumber,email,title);
newper->data=&admin;

Faculty fac= Faculty(name,mnumber,email,tenured,department);
newper->data=&fac;

Student stu= Student(name,mnumber,email,year,major);
newper->data=&stu;
```

Try:

```
Person *admin = new Administrator(name,mnumber,email,title);
newper->data = admin;

Person *fac = new Faculty(name,mnumber,email,tenured,department);
newper->data = fac;

Person * stu = new Student(name,mnumber,email,year,major);
newper->data=stu;
```

Comment: All that does is cause an error to be thrown that there is no suitable conversion function from Faculty to Faculty*


Edit: I added in new before the constructor is called and it solved the problem.

Comment: If `Administrator, Faculty, Student` all inherit from person, you need to use `Person` pointer points to derived types. Polyimorphism will work, isn't it?